# Language Translation Libraries

Tags: machine-translation

I want to translate English to French language so I need to use some
offline translation mechanism instead of online. So can anyone provide
valuable information for language translation libraries which are open source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below URL, see if it helps you
http://digitalforces.blogspot.in/2012/04/offline-google-translator-by-c.html

Comment: Not sure dude, probably play around.